# Cannot read property 'Contract' of undefined. Node api can't interact with smart contract

Tags: web3js, nodejs

I'm using web3 version 1.8.0

[image]

it always shows this error
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Contract')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two import "web3". one is

```
import web3 from 'web3'
```

otherone is

```
// you are using Web3 in your contract
// this is overwriting
import Web3 from 'web3"
```

remove the first one